# Android vitals crash logs deobfuscation pointing to wrong line numbers

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ever since we switched to using App Signing by google play (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) and uploading AABs instead of APKs our deobfuscation for crash logs hasn't been working properly. We used to have to manually upload our mapping file but it seems that this is no longer necessary.

As an example this is our most common crash cluster on the current build (published more than a week ago). This crash is from this morning so the automatically resolved mapping file should be there (I removed package and class name from the trace)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at [REMOVED].onCreateView ([REMOVED].java:44)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:20)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java:584)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.f (FragmentManagerImpl.java:38)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java:46)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.e (FragmentManagerImpl.java:4)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.o (FragmentManagerImpl.java:6)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.f (FragmentController.java:4)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:15)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1395)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7348)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3145)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:180)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:165)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:142)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:70)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

When i try to debug this custom fragment I noticed that line 44 is an empty line not even inside the OnCreateView lifecycle method which makes this stacktrace pretty useless.

Has anyone else experienced the same thing? Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Android Vitals in the crash stack trace displays correct de-obfuscated names for classes and methods, but incorrect too little line numbers, e.g. `MyClass.java:2`, probably corresponding to the lines in the shrinked AAB.
Maybe a solution could be the suggested Crashlytics?

Comment: I'm not sure which SO answer I used to find this but someone pointed out you need to add these lines to proguard for AABs `-useuniqueclassmembernames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable` and that fixed my crash logs at least

Answer (score 0):

To have correct line numbers in Android vitals stack trace, in the `proguard-rules.pro` used to generate the AAB file I added the rule:

```
-keepattributes LineNumberTable,SourceFile
```

As suggested by alexgophermix.
More details on [Decode an obfuscated stack trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace).